# What's the difference between EPSG: 3043 and EPSG: 25831?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, epsg

When I open a layer projected in ArcGIS with EPSG:25831, QGIS detect it as EPSG:3043.

Apparently everything is where it is supposed to be, and checking both [EPSG:25831](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-31n/) and [EPSG:3043](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-tm31/) they appear to have the same bounds.

Is there any reason why QGIS deals with this info as 3043 or it is a bug? Is it possible that not changing it to 25831 can cause my data to be imprecise?

Comment: The difference between the two is that when using EPSG:3043, interchange data should be give in northing,easting order rather than the usual-for-UTM order of easting,northing, as in EPSG:25831.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO,the projection parameters are the same for both codes:

```
+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Important is the contents of the * prj file.
If it contains only the parameters and not EPSG code self, QGIS uses the first suitable parameter entry.